# How do I convert objects to datetime in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code to import from a CSV file

```
    data = pd.read_csv(("dados_meteo.csv"),\
               names=['POM','DTM','RNF','WET','HMD','TMP','DEW','INF'],\
               parse_dates = ['DTM'])
```

then

```
 data.dtypes
```

returns

```
POM     object
DTM     object
RNF    float64
WET    float64
HMD    float64
TMP    float64
DEW    float64
INF      int64
dtype: object
```

After using

```
data['DTM'] = data['DTM'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

The DTM keeps the same type. Could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: can you show a sample of that column?

Comment: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/timeseries.html#converting-to-timestamps

Comment: Here is the example - 2011-11-01 00:00:00

Comment: you must have non-valid dates their; your original spec should work, try specifying ``force=True`` to ``to_datetime`` if it works, then you have some invalid data (that the force kw sets to NaT)

Comment: Like this?
data['DTM'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DTM'], force=True)
It gives me an error: to_datetime() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force'

Comment: sorry ``coerce=True``

Comment: the same error, now with 'coerce' :-(

Comment: you must have an older version of pandas prob should use at least 0.12; 0.13.1 is the current

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48413/discussion-between-hugo-and-jeff)

Answer (score 1):

Check your CSV file date column and make sure it is set to as date type ( or else select column=> right click  =>Format cells=>Under category select Date=>and select date format)

then

```
data =pd.read_csv("dados_meteo.csv",parse_dates=['date-coumn-name-here'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you created your data frame you could convert your object to date time type.
 Here is the way I did

```
pd.to_datetime(data.DTM, errors = 'ignore')
```

If you do not have missing values in your raw data you might not need to use errors = 'ignore'

Hope that helps!